# Window level dependency property (view's code behind), can it be bound to in XAML of the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have defined a dependency property in code behind (.cs) of a view, I want to bind to it a value from my view model.  I was hoping that I could go to the .xaml and bind to it in the top section where the Window is defined and other properties like the DataContext, Title, etc are populated.  It seems this is not possible because the only properties showing up there are that of a base Window type and not the particular instance of the view I'm working with.

The reason I wanted to do this is if my ViewModel defines a command, I wanted to be able to kick off that command from the code behind of my view.  I don't want to cast the DataContext to the particular ViewModel type to get a handle on the command.  I can obviously send a message (I'm using MVVM Light) to do this, it just seemed like perhaps I could do it without messaging via a dependency property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the binding via a Style setter like shown below. Please note the fully qualified property name in the Setter `Property`. You may also be able to set `local:MainWindow` as the Style's `TargetType` to avoid the fully qualified property name, but the XAML Designer might complain about that.

```xml
<Window x:Class="SomeNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace" ...>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:MainWindow.SomeProperty"
                    Value="{Binding ViewModelProperty}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    ...
</Window>
```